# Cleanup in JUnit's @After for specific test case method

Tags: junit, junit4

I'm writing a couple of test cases, which check the work with database. For every test case I have a specific cleanup script. Those cleanup scripts should run anyway no matter how the tests ends. So this is a kind of finally block. It is no secret that try-catch-finally in test method is a bad practice. As an alternative we have a @After in junit4, but it runs after every @Test case.

Is there an approach to customize an @After for specific test case?

Answer (score 0):

Split your test cases into two classes. Define the `@After` only one of them.
If you have some other common methods (like `@Before`) then move them into a utility class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one option would be to use org.junit.rules.TestName, get the name of the method at @After and execute anything what I need for that testMethod.